# How to set multiple values in CascadeChoiceParameter's for referencedParameters

Tags: groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy

Trying to set multiple values in CascadeChoiceParameter's for referencedParameters. What the format should be? Docs [documentation](https://javadoc.jenkins.io/plugin/uno-choice/org/biouno/unochoice/CascadeChoiceParameter.html#%3Cinit%3E(java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,org.biouno.unochoice.model.Script,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.Boolean,java.lang.Integer)) said that it should be 'string', but in case of setting `referencedParameters: 'param1,param2'` it goes to fallback script.
here is the class:

```
[$class: 'CascadeChoiceParameter',
            name: 'SOME_PARAM',
            description: 'some description',
            randomName: '',
            script: [$class: 'GroovyScript',
                fallbackScript: [
                    classpath: [],
                    sandbox: true,
                    script: 'return ["item_1"]'
                ],
                script: [
                    classpath: [],
                    sandbox: true,
                    script: """
                        if(PARAM_2.equals("some_value") && PARAM_3.equals("some_value")) {
                            return ["item_1", "item_2", "item_3"]
                        } else if((PARAM_2.equals("E2E_Tests") || (PARAM_2.equals("Real_API"))  && PARAM_3.equals("knox_guard"))  {
                            return ["item_1", "item_2", "item_4"]
                        } else {
                            return ["item_1"]
                        }
                         """.stripIndent()
                ]
            ],
            choiceType: 'PT_SINGLE_SELECT',
            referencedParameters: 'PARAM_2,PARAM_3',
            filterable: false,
            filterLength: 1
        ],
```

Comment: Did you got any solutions for this? i am also facing the same.
it would be helpful if you share full code

Answer (score 0):

The fallback script is used if/when there is any kind of exception/error when attempting to execute the main script. In your case, there is a compilation error in the `else if((PARAM_2.equals("E2E_Tests") || (PARAM_2.equals("Real_API"))  && PARAM_3.equals("knox_guard"))` line. All the open parenthesis haven't been closed - there are 6 open parenthesis and only 5 close parenthesis. Anyway, I haven't tested a `CascadeChoiceParameter` version of the pipeline. I have tested using `activeChoiceReactiveParam`. Below is a working job DSL:

```
String choicesScript = """
  if(PARAM_2.equals("some_value") && PARAM_3.equals("some_value")) {
      return ["item_1", "item_2", "item_3"]
  } else if((PARAM_2.equals("E2E_Tests") || (PARAM_2.equals("Real_API"))  && PARAM_3.equals("knox_guard")))  {
      return ["item_1", "item_2", "item_4"]
  } else {
      return ["item_5"]
  }
""".stripIndent()

String pipeline = '''
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('Show parameter values') {
            steps {
                echo "PARAM_2: ${params.PARAM_2}, PARAM_3: ${params.PARAM_3}, SOME_PARAM: ${params.SOME_PARAM}"
            }
        }
    }
}
'''.stripIndent()

pipelineJob('reactive-params') {
  parameters {
    activeChoiceParam('PARAM_2') {
      description('First test parameter')
      choiceType('SINGLE_SELECT')
      groovyScript {
        script('return ["some_value", "E2E_Tests", "Real_API"]')
      }
    }

    activeChoiceParam('PARAM_3') {
      description('Second test parameter')
      choiceType('SINGLE_SELECT')
      groovyScript {
        script('return ["some_value", "knox_guard"]')
      }
    }
    
    activeChoiceReactiveParam('SOME_PARAM') {
      description('some description')
      choiceType('SINGLE_SELECT')
      referencedParameter('PARAM_2')
      referencedParameter('PARAM_3')
      groovyScript {
        script(choicesScript)
        fallbackScript('return ["item_1"]')
      }
    }
  }
  
  definition {
    cps {
      script(pipeline)
    }
  }  
}
```